# UBUNTU - I am not asked for password after logging in with fingerprint

Tags: ubuntu, password, gnome-keyring, fingerprint

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME on a Dell XPS 13.
I use the fingerprint as the main identification method, so I don't have to type the password each time I use `sudo`.
The expected behavior is to log in using the fingerprint and then be asked for my password only once right after log in.

My problem is that more often than not I am not asked for the password after log in, so the keyring is not unlocked.
I have to log out and then log in again after waiting for fingerprint identification time out or using the wrong finger so I can enter the password and unlock the keyring.

The behaviour is unpredictable. Is there a way to troubleshoot it or to unlock the keyring after login?

EDIT

Just to add more information, when I try to unlock the keyring using seahorse, the "unlock" button does not work.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and clarify when you were expecting to be asked for a password? Is it when running terminal commands with sudo? Something else? What's the point of using the fingerprint if you still need to enter a password?

Comment: What I expect is to be asked for a password after logging in to the desktop using the fingerprint. When that happens, I can use the fingerprint in terminal with sudo etc. Most often that *doesn't* happen, so the keyring is not unlocked and have problems using Evolution, Chrome etc.

Comment: So you would like the keyring (I guess this is Gnome?) to be unlocked with the finger? Or must there be a second authentication where you enter the password? And, if so, why not just use the password in the first place instead of the finger? I'm sure I'm just not understanding something, but maybe you could edit and clarify.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question, hope it is more clear now.